# How do I install ArcGIS Developer help in Visual Studio Express 2008?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development

I would like to install ArcGIS 10 Developer help in VS Express (2008) so that it works with the F1 key. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F1 help does not navigate to the correct ArcObjects page when working in VB .NET
Depending on the version of Visual Studio you're using, you may experience an issue when using F1 help and the Microsoft Document Explorer in Visual Basic (VB) .NET. The functionality of the VB .NET F1 help depends on your settings for where to look for help.
If you're not getting the correct results when you have an ArcObjects component selected, adjust the Microsoft Document Explorer settings to search local help first as shown in the following steps:

1. Open the Microsoft Document Explorer.
2. Click Tools, click Options, then click the Help node.
3. Under the Help node, click Online.
4. Verify that "Try local first" and "online" are both selected under the "When loading help content" area.

The help order needs to be set through the Document Explorer in Visual Studio. If it's set in the stand-alone help system from the start menu, it will not fix the F1 help navigation.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000016n000000